# peewee save changed fields only

Tags: python-3.x, peewee

I have this model in `peewee`:

```
class User(Model):
    username = CharField()
    password = CharField()
    
    class Meta:
        database = db
```

I change password and save the model like this:

```
u = User.get()
u.password = 'newpassword'
u.save()
```

It update both username and password but i want to update password only.

Comment: do you mean **dirty fields**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable `only_save_dirty` meta option and call `save()` like before, `peewee` will save dirty fields only.

**Definition:**

```
class User(Model):
    username = CharField()
    password = CharField()
    
    class Meta:
        database = db
        only_save_dirty = True
```

**Usage:**

```
u = User.get()
u.password = 'newpassword'
u.save()  # username will not updated in DB
```

Comment: This is a pretty all-or-nothing approach. I added this due to user requests, but it's typically much better to be explicit. I don't really recommend using this feature.

Comment: @coleifer Popular web frameworks save only dirty fields by default.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dirty_fields`:

```
u = User.get()
u.password = 'new password'
u.save(only=u.dirty_fields)
```

http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/api.html#Model.dirty_fields

Comment: how should i set `u.dirty_fields`?

Comment: It is set automatically bro.